Why does my onHitEntity only fire sometimes? Minecraft forge net.minecraftforge:forge:1.20-46.0.12
I created a drone in minecraft and gave it some goals which it executes well. Currently I'm having an issue that i cannot for the life of me figure out. so the drone currently shoots an arrow. the arrow will later be a laser but for now i just need the logic to work. So I'm having a couple of problems but the main one is that the arrows when hitting an entity does not always fire the onHitEntity override...
i can see the arrow spawn. i see the arrow fly towards the creeper. i see the creeper get hit. then the arrow bounces off like the creeper is made of iron and the event never triggers.
Snipped of my class:
public class LaserProjectile extends AbstractArrow {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final EntityDataAccessor<Integer> CUSTOM_DATA = SynchedEntityData.defineId(LaserProjectile.class, EntityDataSerializers.INT);
    private static final EntityDataAccessor<Boolean> CRITICAL = SynchedEntityData.defineId(LaserProjectile.class, EntityDataSerializers.BOOLEAN);
    // Example custom data
    private int customData;

    public LaserProjectile(EntityType<? extends AbstractArrow> entityType, Level world) {
        super(entityType, world);
    }

    public LaserProjectile(EntityType<? extends AbstractArrow> entityType, double x, double y, double z, Level world) {
        super(entityType, x, y, z, world);
    }

    public LaserProjectile(EntityType<? extends AbstractArrow> entityType, LivingEntity shooter, Level world) {
        super(entityType, shooter, world);
    }

    public LaserProjectile(Level level, LivingEntity shooter) {
        super(EntityType.ARROW, shooter, level);
        this.setOwner(shooter);
        this.setNoGravity(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHitEntity(EntityHitResult ray) {
        super.onHitEntity(ray);
        LOGGER.debug("hitting enemy!");
        DamageSource damageSource = this.damageSources().indirectMagic(this, this.getOwner());
        ray.getEntity().hurt(damageSource, 6.0F);
        this.discard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHitBlock(BlockHitResult ray) {
        super.onHitBlock(ray);
        this.discard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tickDespawn() {
        if (this.inGroundTime > 60) {
            this.discard();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected @NotNull ItemStack getPickupItem() {
        return new ItemStack(Items.ARROW);
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        super.tick();
        if (!this.level().isClientSide && this.getOwner() != null) {
            this.setPos(this.getOwner().getX(), this.getOwner().getEyeY(), this.getOwner().getZ());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void defineSynchedData() {
        super.defineSynchedData();
        this.entityData.define(CRITICAL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void addAdditionalSaveData(CompoundTag compound) {
        super.addAdditionalSaveData(compound);
        compound.putBoolean("Critical", this.isCritArrow());
    }

    @Override
    public void readAdditionalSaveData(CompoundTag compound) {
        super.readAdditionalSaveData(compound);
        this.setCritArrow(compound.getBoolean("Critical"));
    }

    public boolean isCritArrow() {
        return this.entityData.get(CRITICAL);
    }

    public void setCritArrow(boolean critical) {
        this.entityData.set(CRITICAL, critical);
    }
}



and this is the goal class i created for it:
public class AttackHostileMobsGoal extends Goal {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final int ATTACK_COOLDOWN_TICKS = 200; // Cooldown in ticks (1 second)
    private final PathfinderMob entity;
    private final double attackRange;
    private final double followSpeed;
    private LivingEntity target;
    private int ticksSinceLastAttack = ATTACK_COOLDOWN_TICKS;

    public AttackHostileMobsGoal(PathfinderMob entity, double attackRange, double followSpeed) {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.attackRange = attackRange;
        this.followSpeed = followSpeed;
        this.setFlags(EnumSet.of(Goal.Flag.MOVE, Goal.Flag.LOOK));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canUse() {
        List<Monster> nearbyHostileMobs = this.entity.level().getEntitiesOfClass(Monster.class, this.entity.getBoundingBox().inflate(attackRange));
        if (!nearbyHostileMobs.isEmpty()) {
            this.target = nearbyHostileMobs.get(0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canContinueToUse() {
        return this.target != null && this.target.isAlive() && this.entity.distanceToSqr(this.target) <= attackRange * attackRange;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        this.entity.getNavigation().moveTo(this.target, this.followSpeed);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.target = null;
        this.entity.getNavigation().stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        if (this.target != null && this.entity.distanceToSqr(this.target) <= attackRange * attackRange) {
            this.entity.getLookControl().setLookAt(this.target, 30.0F, 30.0F);

            if (ticksSinceLastAttack >= ATTACK_COOLDOWN_TICKS) {
                attackWithLaser(this.target);
                ticksSinceLastAttack = 0; // Reset cooldown
            } else {
                ticksSinceLastAttack++;
            }
        } else {
            this.entity.getNavigation().moveTo(this.target, this.followSpeed);
        }
    }


    private void attackWithLaser(LivingEntity target) {
        // Calculate the direction from the entity to the target
        Vec3 direction = new Vec3(target.getX() - this.entity.getX(), target.getEyeY() - this.entity.getEyeY(), target.getZ() - this.entity.getZ());
        double distance = direction.length(); // length is used instead of sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

        // Normalize the direction vector
        direction = direction.normalize();

        // Create and initialize the laser projectile
        LaserProjectile laser = new LaserProjectile(this.entity.level(), this.entity);
        double startX = this.entity.getX() + direction.x * 1.0D;
        double startY = this.entity.getEyeY() + direction.y * 1.0D;
        double startZ = this.entity.getZ() + direction.z * 1.0D;

        //LOGGER.debug("Entity Position: X=" + this.entity.getX() + ", Y=" + this.entity.getEyeY() + ", Z=" + this.entity.getZ());
        //LOGGER.debug("Target Position: X=" + target.getX() + ", Y=" + target.getEyeY() + ", Z=" + target.getZ());


        // Shoot the projectile with a specified speed and no gravity
        laser.shoot(direction.x, direction.y, direction.z, 1.5F, 0.0F);

        // Set the starting position of the projectile
        laser.setPos(startX, startY, startZ);
        // Spawn the projectile in the world
        this.entity.level().addFreshEntity(laser);
    }


}

does anyone know what im doing wrong?
